# Crawl Only HTML Pages

Tags: java, regex, web-crawler

I want to crawl onyl html pages so when I changed the regular expression here in this code.. it is still crawling some xml page also.. Any suggestions why is it happening..

```
public class MyCrawler extends WebCrawler {


    Pattern filters = Pattern.compile("(.(html))");

    public MyCrawler() {
    }

    public boolean shouldVisit(WebURL url) {
        String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
        if (filters.matcher(href).matches()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (href.startsWith("http://www.somehost.com/")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void visit(Page page) {
        int docid = page.getWebURL().getDocid();

        String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();         
        String text = page.getText();
        List<WebURL> links = page.getURLs();
        int parentDocid = page.getWebURL().getParentDocid();

        System.out.println("Docid: " + docid);
        System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
        System.out.println("Number of links: " + links.size());
        System.out.println("Docid of parent page: " + parentDocid);
        System.out.println("=============");
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Lucero: That should be an answer.

Comment: @Lucero, thanks for replying.. Yeah thanks for pointing out about xhtml, I would like to do this for html and xhtml both.. So how we can analyze the content-type in this case so that it crawl only html and xhtml..

Comment: @Jim, it didn't really feel like a real answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension is meaningless on the web - especially with newer "SEO"-type paths. You have to analyze it's content-type.

You can do this by requesting (with the HTTP `GET` or possibly `HEAD` method) each URL and analyze its response headers. If the Content-Type response header is not what you want, you don't have to download it - otherwise it's what you want to look at.

Edit: HTML should have `text/html` as content-type, XHTML is `application/xhtml+xml` (but note that the latter may be subject to content-negotiation, which is usually dependent on the content of your accept header and the user agent in the request).

You can find all the information about the HTTP headers [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

Comment: thanks for replying.. Yeah thanks for pointing out about xhtml, I would like to do this for html and xhtml both.. So how we can analyze the content-type in this case so that it crawl only html and xhtml..